# Accessing applications without login from a centralized application in Oracle APEX

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, oracle-apex

I have several applications written in Oracle Forms & Reports 10g (ie. fmb & rdf) and I publish them through Oracle Application Server 10g. I have a main application that I redirect to after SSO (Single-Sign-On) login. I open other applications from this main application and since I use SSO, users aren't asked to enter username and password in each application.

I initiated migration to Oracle APEX and I want to setup the same scneario in APEX. I want to have a main APEX application that users have to login and then I want to open other applications (from that main application) without logining again. By the way I also want the users directed to login page in each application if they did not open the application from main application (ie. entered the URL of specific application to address bar manually).

How can I do that in Oracle APEX environment?

Answer (score 0):

This will solve half your problem
http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2014/04/shared-authentication-across-multiple-apex-apps.html

There are also a few articles out there describing how to set up APEX using SSO

http://www.yenlo.nl/nl/how-to-implement-single-sign-on-using-ntlm/

and oracle white papers
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/sso-partner-app-100552.html